# Is there a portable way to get the name of the WiFi card on the command line without additional parsing?

Tags: command-line, wifi, network-interface

In [this tool](https://github.com/hq6/WPAManager), the name of the wireless interface is hardcoded to be `wlan0`. This was a reasonable assumption up through Ubuntu 14.04, but the wireless interface name appears to have changed in Ubuntu 15.10.

I would like to modify the tool to detect the name of the first wireless interface at run time.

One way to do this is to parse the name out of the output of `iwconfig`.

```
iwconfig 2>&1 | grep ESSID | awk '{print $1}' | head -n 1
```

Unfortunately, this approach seems rather fragile, because it depends on the output formatting of `iwconfig`.

**Is there a portable, more direct command for getting the names of the wireless interfaces on the command line?**

Comment: `iw dev | awk '/Interface/ {print $2}'`

Comment: @jasonwryan, Does the spec of `iw` ensure that its output will not change?

Comment: Well, `iw dev` is designed to output the device name; so it seems unlikely. However, it is never guaranteed and it is a much more robust approach than your old method... See https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/documentation/iw

Comment: Would `ip link` be appropriate for this sort of thing?

Comment: Things to keep in mind: "the first wireless interface" may not be "the active wireless interface", there may be more than one active wireless interface, and an active wireless interface is not necessarily the interface with a default route.

Answer (score 0):

On Linux, the network devices are listed in `/sys/class/net/`. Each device has an entry there and its type is given by `/sys/class/net/$finame/type`. The types are defined in `if_arp.h`:

```
#define ARPHRD_IEEE80211 801            /* IEEE 802.11
```

You should be able to find all devices of a given type with:

```
find_by_type() {
(
    cd /sys/class/net/ || return 1
    for dev in * ; do
        if test "$(cat "$dev/type")" = "$1" ; then
            echo $dev
        fi
    done
)
}
```

You can then:

```
wlan="$(find_by_type 801 | head -n1)"
```

This only works for Linux, however.

Comment: type are all equals to 1 in my case (Ubuntu Server 18.04)